# ie11: Insert and delete html table row after a row with a class name

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JSP page. When page renders based on certain conditions

1)I have to insert a row to an existing table which has a row with a class name "details" OR
2) delete the inserted row if it exists

Page has to render in ie11 as well. So I cannot use insertAfter() or any es6 methods. I'm unable to append/ remove at the right node

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/og52nkjh/)

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="details">
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

var newHtml = '<tr class="select__pcp"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td class="txt-right">text Msg</td><td class="txt-right span2"></td></tr>';

if(condition) {
// insert newHTML after <tr class="details">
} else {
//if <tr> with class="select__pcp" exists then delete it
}
```

Comment: IE doesn't allow you to set HTML of `table` or `tr` elements, you've to build the rows and cells manually. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `appendChild`: see this page(https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_node_appendchild.asp)

and `removeChild`: see this page(https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_node_removechild.asp)

and if you add a node in special place you need to use `insertAdjacentElement`: see this page(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacentelement.asp)

Comment: You can't use `appendChild` to insert a row into a specific position in a table.

Comment: What's wrong with the native row/cell insert methods? They feel the most natural choise when working with tables.

Answer (score 0):

To Add: You can try setting the `outerHTML` of the `details` element to include the new element.

To Remove: you can set the `outerHTML` to an empty string

---on snippet load: adds element to table, waits 3 seconds and removes element.

```js
var newHtml = '<tr class="select__pcp"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td class="txt-right">text Msg</td><td class="txt-right span2"></td></tr>';

function removeOrAdd(action){
 if(action) {
  document.querySelector('.details').outerHTML += newHtml
 } else {
 document.querySelector('.select__pcp').outerHTML = ''
 }
}

removeOrAdd(true)
setTimeout(removeOrAdd, 3000, false)
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="details">
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```